# unzip_file not working with the remote file

Tags: wp-filesystem, ziparchive

I'm trying to use [unzip_file](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unzip_file/) to extract the remote archive with no success. It works only with the local path using **get_template_directory()** but with a remote zip archive URL I'm getting *Incompatible Archive.* message.

Here is the stripped version of my code:

```
WP_Filesystem();
global $wp_filesystem;

$source = 'http://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/ona-creative.1.0.0.zip';
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $source, get_theme_root() );

if ( is_wp_error( $unzipfile ) ) {
    wp_send_json(
        array(
            'done'    => 1,
            'message' => esc_html__( $unzipfile->get_error_message() . ' There was an error unzipping the file.', 'ona' )
        )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: How about first downloading it to your folder structure and then doing the unzip function?

Comment: You do not have the proper rights to write in http://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/
You havet e first download the ZIP file and then extract it. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50094/wp-remote-get-downloading-and-saving-files

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a read permissions not write. Since there is no mention of this in docs I got confused. Yes, saving local copy works.

Comment: if your goal is to download and install a theme from .org wouldn't it be easier to ask how to do that? WP already has code to do this internally, you don't have to download and unzip it yourself

Answer (score 0):

As **@Buttered_Toast** and **@Sébastien Serre** mentioned I first need to save file to a local directory before unzipping. So here is my final code:

```
$source = 'http://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/ona-creative.1.0.0.zip';
$file = get_theme_root() . '/' . $slug . '.zip';
file_put_contents( $file, file_get_contents( $source ));
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $file, get_theme_root() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in APIs instead, e.g. here is a snippet from the AJAX handler for the theme admin screen:

```php
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/theme.php';
 
    $api = themes_api(
        'theme_information',
        array(
            'slug'   => $slug,
            'fields' => array( 'sections' => false ),
        )
    );
 
    if ( is_wp_error( $api ) ) {
        $status['errorMessage'] = $api->get_error_message();
        wp_send_json_error( $status );
    }
 
    $skin     = new WP_Ajax_Upgrader_Skin();
    $upgrader = new Theme_Upgrader( $skin );
    $result   = $upgrader->install( $api->download_link );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_install_theme/

`$slug` was the slug of the theme, e.g. `ona-creative`, you don't have to download and unzip the theme yourself, let WP do the heavy lifting for you.